# RGEE getting pixel values and latitude and longitude

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, pixel

I am using Google Earth Engine on R. I'm trying to get a data set with the latitude and longitude of each pixel along with the value from the GEE Image Collection.

I know its been done in JavaScript - I just can't translate it over.

```
library(scales)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(cshapes)
library(rgee)
  ee_Initialize()
  #ee_reattach() # reattach ee as a reserve word
  #Adds a band containing image date as years since 1991.
  
 # Map the time band creation helper over the collection.
  
  collection <- ee$
    ImageCollection('JRC/GHSL/P2016/SMOD_POP_GLOBE_V1')$
    select('smod_code')
  
  collection2 <- collection$filter(ee$Filter$date('2010-01-01', '2015-02-01')) 

##### Creating the Shapefile 
b <- cshp(date = as.Date("1990-01-01"))

SouthAfrica <- c()
SouthAfrica2 <- c()
SouthAfrica<- b@polygons[[154]]@Polygons[[2]]@coords
  for(j in 1:nrow(SouthAfrica)){
    SouthAfrica2 <- c(SouthAfrica2, SouthAfrica[j,])
  }
SouthAfricaShap <- ee$Geometry$Polygon(SouthAfrica2)
  

##### Beginning the Conversion #####

SouthAfrica2000 <- collection2$filterBounds(SouthAfricaShap)
ImageSouthAfrica2000 <- SouthAfrica2000$first()
ImageSouthAfrica2000 <- ImageSouthAfrica2000$select('smod_code')

coordsImage = ee$Image$pixelLonLat()$reproject(ImageSouthAfrica2000$projection())
joinedImage = coordsImage$addBands(ImageSouthAfrica2000)

valuesList <- joinedImage$reduceRegion(c(
  reducer= ee$Reducer$toList() ,
  geometry=  SouthAfricaShap
))$values()$get(0)

print(valuesList)
```

The value list function is what's not working! I would love any help I can get!

THE ERROR THAT SHOWS UP IS REALLY MESSY AND SAYS THIS:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  EEException: Invalid argument for ee.Reducer(): ({'reducer': <ee.Reducer object at 0x1241129e8>, 'geometry': ee.Geometry({
  "functionInvocationValue": {
    "functionName": "GeometryConstructors.Polygon",
    "arguments": {
      "coordinates": {
        "constantValue": [
          [
            [
              13.20889117993994,
              -16.97360893198885
            ],
            [
              13.260827179988269,
              -16.984863931999314
            ],
            [
              13.317782180041377,
              -16.97805493199303
            ],
            [
              13.34630918006792,
              -16.970672931986087
            ],
            [
              13.376036180095525,
              -16.970908931986344
            ],
            [
              13.472082180185055,
              -17.010835932023554
            ],
            [
              13.494300180205641,
              -17.02555493203721
            ],
            [
              1
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error? Or is nothing returned? Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks so much for fixing my question! Yes I am getting an error. Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  EEException: Invalid argument for ee.Reducer(): ({'reducer': <ee.Reducer object at 0x124149a90>, 'geometry': ee.Geometry({
  "functionInvocationValue": {
    "functionName": "GeometryConstructors.Polygon",
    "arguments": {
      "coordinates": {
        "constantValue": [
          [
            [
              13.20889117993994,
              -16.97360893198885
          ....

Comment: @Spacedman I have no idea what this means but I think it just doesn't like the valuelist

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code, consider that:

- **rgee** can convert automatically sf objects into EE objects using **sf_as_ee**.
- In **valuesList** there is no need to put arguments inside a list or a vector.

```r
library(raster)
library(scales)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(cshapes)
library(rgee)
library(sf)
library(sp)

ee_Initialize()
#ee_reattach() # reattach ee as a reserve word
#Adds a band containing image date as years since 1991.

# Map the time band creation helper over the collection.

collection <- ee$
  ImageCollection('JRC/GHSL/P2016/SMOD_POP_GLOBE_V1')$
  select('smod_code')

collection2 <- collection$filter(ee$Filter$date('2010-01-01', '2015-02-01')) 

##### Creating the Shapefile 
SouthAfricaShap <- cshp(date = as.Date("1990-01-01")) %>% 
  '['(154,) %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  sf_as_ee()
Map$centerObject(SouthAfricaShap)
Map$addLayer(SouthAfricaShap)


##### Beginning the Conversion #####
SouthAfrica2000 <- collection2$filterBounds(SouthAfricaShap)
ImageSouthAfrica2000 <- SouthAfrica2000$first()
ImageSouthAfrica2000 <- ImageSouthAfrica2000$select('smod_code')

coordsImage = ee$Image$pixelLonLat()$reproject(ImageSouthAfrica2000$projection())
joinedImage = coordsImage$addBands(ImageSouthAfrica2000)

valuesList <- joinedImage$reduceRegion(
  reducer= ee$Reducer$toList() ,
  geometry=  SouthAfricaShap
)$values()$get(0)

print(valuesList$getInfo())
```

Comment: Cesar, can we get a vector parameter along with the list when we have multiple areas for ex.? how can one pass this to the reducer?